# Storing FQL returned JSON to SQL Server 

Tags: c#, sql-server, json, facebook-fql

I am using FQL to retrieve data from graph API and here is the output

```
 {   "data": [
     {
       "value": 74
     }, 
     {
       "value": 131
     }, 
     {
       "value": 167
     }, 
     {
       "value": 114
     }, 
     {
       "value": 49
     } }
```

How can I store this data to a single column in SQL Server through C#??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the following C# classes for your jSON data:

```
public class DataValue
{
    public int value { get; set; }
}

public class DataValues
{
    public List<DataValue> data { get; set; }
}
```

If you are using webmethod:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)] 
public static string GetData(DataValues dataValues)
{

foreach var datavalue in dataValues.data
{
'write your insert logic
}

}
```

Comment: My main intention is to store the values 74,131,167.....in different rows of the same column so that when i retrieve them by date...i can get all the data..

how i can process this JSON data to pick 74,131,167 etc an push them to different rows of the same column in C#?